# Facebook FQL returns different data for same permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the user's feed using FQL.
I use the following statement (bring video posts):

```
SELECT created_time, post_id, actor_id, message, attachment, likes.count, likes.friends,
comments.count FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE
uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0 AND 'video' in attachment
```

I asked for the "read_stream" permission and got the user's token

MY PROBLEM:
when using the "Graph API Explorer" (facebook's page) I get a post which a friend of mine "Liked" - the author of that post is not my friend.

HOWEVER,
when using the access_token of my own application (not Graph API Explorer's token), I can't see that post !!

I used the "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=" to check that both tokens have the same permissions....
btw, I was able to get the post using a "WHERE post_id=" - so it doesn't seem like a user permission problem as well.

ANY IDEA????
I AM STUCK HERE!!!

PLS...................................

Comment: Has your friend authorised the graph api explorer? have both apps got the same settings for migrations? (i guess you can't check this for graph api explorer, but for your app and a second app you can)

Comment: my friend is not using the graph api and didn't authorize it. what does migration settings on my application has to do with it? my app is using the default settings there. should I change something?

Answer (score 0):

On the Graph API Explorer page, if you want to see exactly the results that you would get in your application, you have to specify that the access token which you get is for the application.  You can do this by clicking the drop-down in the top right corner of the page and selecting your application.

It probably says "Graph API Explorer" in the drop down by default so you would get different results than the app even if the permissions are the same.